# Is it possible to set a viewport for iOS only through CSS, without meta-tag

Tags: ios, css, viewport

I need to use viewport on a page where all I can change is CSS. That means that I don't have an access to HTML, so I can't put the famous **meta-tag** there.

The only possible option I have found which could work is

```
@viewport {
    width: device-width;
    initial-scale: 1;
    zoom: 1;
    min-zoom: 1;
    max-zoom: 2;
    zoom: fixed;
}
```

But I didn't manage to get a proper result. It still saves the same width when I am rotating the device.

Does anybody have some ideas what should I change? Or is it possible at all?

Comment: I understand that I cannot inject HTML. My question is about CSS viewport property vs. iOS

Comment: You could load different css with custom width property on each rotation mode. You can get it in `[UIDevice currentDevice].orientation`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of writing this (Dez '13), the [CSS Device Adaption](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-device-adapt/) (including `@viewport`) is not ready to use and has far from perfect browser support. Therefor, **setting a viewport for iOS only through CSS is *currently* not possible.**

**Browser support:**

- Internet Explorer 10 ([msdn.microsoft.com](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh708740%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) – vendor-prefixed: `@-ms-viewport`
- Opera Mobile 11 ([dev.opera.com](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/an-introduction-to-meta-viewport-and-viewport/)) – vendor-prefixed: `@-o-viewport`

**Further information:**

- html5hacks.com: [Elegantly Resize Your Page With the @-viewport CSS Declaration](http://html5hacks.com/blog/2012/11/28/elegantly-resize-your-page-with-the-at-viewport-css-declaration/)
- treehouse blog: [CSS Device Adaptation With @viewport](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/thinking-ahead-css-device-adaptation-with-viewport)
- As of the [Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#browsers) IE10 in Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8 need some fixes to work properly:

> ### Internet Explorer 10 in Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8
>
> Internet Explorer 10 doesn't differentiate **device width** from **viewport width**, and thus doesn't properly apply the media queries in Bootstrap's CSS. Normally you'd just add a quick snippet of CSS to fix this:
>
> ```
> @-ms-viewport       { width: device-width; }
> ```
>
> However, this doesn't work as it causes Windows Phone 8 devices to show a mostly desktop view instead of narrow "phone" view. To address this, you'll need to **include the following CSS and JavaScript to work around the bug until Microsoft issues a fix.**
>
> **CSS:**
>
> ```
> @-webkit-viewport   { width: device-width; }
> @-moz-viewport      { width: device-width; }
> @-ms-viewport       { width: device-width; }
> @-o-viewport        { width: device-width; }
> @viewport           { width: device-width; }
> ```
>
> **JS:**
>
> ```
> if (navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/10.0/)) {
>   var msViewportStyle = document.createElement("style")
>   msViewportStyle.appendChild(
>     document.createTextNode(
>       "@-ms-viewport{width:auto!important}"
>     )
>   )
>   document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(msViewportStyle)
> }
> ```
>
> For more information and usage guidelines, read [Windows Phone 8 and Device-Width](http://timkadlec.com/2013/01/windows-phone-8-and-device-width/).